# Rounding to two decimals via Visual basic (Microsoft access)

Tags: vb.net, rounding

in my database I have code similar to this

```
Dim Ulaz As String, Izlaz As String, UkKol As String, UkFin As String
```

and at the end of the code I have this

```
Me.NC = UkFin / UkKol
```

`Me.NC` respresents avaerage price.

If for result I have `0.498` value, I would like for that value to be shown as `0.50`. In another words, it must be rounded to two places.

How can I do that in VB? That value will be passed to `NC` field on Form, however..

Many thanks in advance for prompt reply!

All the best,
Adi

Comment: I am seeing some confusion here. Your title says you are using Microsoft Access, but have tagged it vb.net. Do you mean VBA in Access, or VB.NET which is communicating to an Access database?

Comment: I have always a moment of discomfort when I see a string divided by another string. It goes against every thing I have learned. Do yourself a favor and try to use Option Strict On

Answer (score 1):

You want the `Math.Round` method.  Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .ToString() method with a format string to display the number with as many decimal places as you would like without losing any accuracy on the actual variable.

```
Me.NC.ToString("f2")
```

or

```
Me.NC.ToString("0.00")
```

Here is some more information on format strings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx